# Error in NSTimer (Swift: Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift2, nstimer, xcode7

I am making a timer that will call a function repeatedly with swift 2, Xcode 7. This function sends a local push notification. My timer variable is declared outside the viewDidLoad() in ViewController.swift.

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self ,       selector: Selector("notification"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I am getting an error:

Argument Type 'NSObject -> () -> ViewController does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'

It seems there is some problem with the target self as it is highlighted in red.

**Here is my full code if needed:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var time = 10
 var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self , selector: Selector("notification"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func btnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
 let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "You won!", message: "Press Go to continue!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

}

func notification(){
    time--
    if (time == 0){


    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertAction = "Go back to App!"
    notification.alertBody = "Pls Go back to my App!"
    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
        timer.invalidate()

}
}

}
```

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to declare the var timer only setting as NSTimer.init() like:

```
var timer = NSTimer.init()
```

And then, put the initialization with scheduledTimerWithInterval inside viewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "notification", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```